# backflow-preventer valve: "shall provide protection where a potential health hazard does not exist": can it be used in a house?

Tags: plumbing, backflow-preventer

> Ideal for use where Lead-Free valves are required. Designed
> for installation on potable water lines to protect against both
> backsiphonage and backpressure of polluted water into the
> potable water supply. **[This model] shall provide protection where a potential health hazard does not exist.**
>
> ASSE® Listed 1024
>
> CSA® Certified
>
> Meets the requirements of NSF/ANSI/CAN 61*

Does this language on the specification indicate that the valve  may, or may not, be used indoors on the house side of the water meter? I'm confused by the fact that it can protect against polluted water being siphoned back into the potable water supply and yet it shall be used where there's no risk of health hazard.

EDIT: While I was trying to search the internet for an answer to my question I found [this CDC document relating to *legionella*](https://www.cdc.gov/legionella/wmp/control-toolkit/potable-water-systems.html#:%7E:text=Store%20and%20circulate%20cold%20water,throughout%20the%20potable%20water%20system.).

Comment: They are used in the house.  Mainly near where city water comes in so street pipe work does not siphon water out of the house(hot water tank).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Levels of hazard

The US plumbing codes call out different backflow preventers for different applications based on the level of risk involved.  Your dual check valve is intended for lower-hazard applications where the worst risk is water that say is a bit rusty, smelly, or discolored, such as an iron-piped fire sprinkler system.

As you increase the hazard from mere pollution to health-risking contamination, the codes require more robust preventers to be installed.  For instance, the contamination risk posed by an irrigation system with a chemical feeder and pump in it would require a reduced pressure zone backflow preventer instead of your dual check valve.  This extends up to the highest hazard possible, namely exposure to raw sewage, where the codes require the easily inspected and mechanical-failure-free protection provided by an air gap.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought it might mean that it was for use with a well and not with municipal water.

Answer (score 4):

Well, *anything* can be a potential health hazard, including unpolluted [dihydrogen monoxide](https://www.dhmo.org/dihydrogen-monoxide/). I suspect that this language is *trying* to say is:

- This valve prevents *normal* usage from backing up into the supply lines.
- This valve is **not** to be used when *known **serious** health hazards* are involved. Which might mean things like pipes going into refineries or chemical processing plants or nuclear power plants (you can never put too much water in a nuclear reactor) or similar.

Comment: But the references to potable water lines and NSF/ANSI/CAN 61 would indicate that it's intended to be used in a typical single-family dwelling, right?

Comment: Technically, no. If I understand correctly, those rules/regs would apply anywhere that potable water is supplied - residential, commercial, etc. But that is all typical language for ordinary single-family-home stuff.

Comment: @mrblint  Homes yes.  Main use is sprinkler/garden hose pipes(nasty things as I am drinking out of one), but any water pipe you do not want backflow.

Comment: What would actually help figure it out is the actual manufacturer/model # of the item.

Comment: This was my second thought. Right after "classic CYA language."

Comment: It's a Zurn/Wilkins 700XL. dual check valve.  But I've seen the identical language used by other manufacturers.

Comment: @mrblint I'm sure it is fine. Standard legalese. The important part - which I couldn't say until I Google'd it - is that this is a US manufacturer. (Parts might be made elsewhere, but to their specs.) So I would reasonably take them at their word regarding lead and the various approvals, etc. Which I would **not** say for certain brands that are shipped around the world on a big river.